# circular spherical sector in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

In my course of complex analysis there is the definition

let $\beta \in ]0,\pi[, r \in ]0,+\infty[, x \in \mathbb{R}², \nu \in \partial B_2(0,1) $. Then we define the circular spherical sector of opening $\beta$, radius $r$, vertex $x$ and direction $\nu$ to be the set
$$\Gamma_{\beta,r}(x,\nu):=\{\zeta \in \mathbb{R}²: \cos\Big(\frac{\beta}{2}\Big)|\zeta-x|<\nu(\zeta-x), |\zeta -x|<r\}$$

But I don't understand how this set is geometrically. I think it is like a slice of circle ("slice of pizza" visually makes more) of opening $\beta$. But what is the role of $r$, $x$ and $\nu$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it is like a slice of pizza. It is an open sector of the open disk with center $x$ and radius $r$ (note $\lvert \zeta - x \rvert < r$).

[image]

The angle enclosed by the two radii (black line segments) of the red sector is $\beta$. The angle bisector has direction $\nu$ (which is a vector lying on the unit circle).

Comment: thank you very much, very clear